# How to simplify this output with ArcTan[Tan XXXX ]

Tags: simplifying-expressions

```
Integrate[Tan[3 x]^2, x]
```

[image]

Why couldn't it simplify the answer to

> -x + 1/3 Tan[3x]

so to speak

Comment: `Integrate[Tan[3 x]^2, x] // PowerExpand`

Comment: The problem is that ArcTan is a multivalued function. Therefore ArcTan[x] needs not be equal to x. If you want to force this, you have to restrict the argument of ArcTan e.g. to the interval -Pi/2..Pi/2. With this your expression will simplifys: Simplify[ArcTan[Tan[3 x]]/3 + Tan[3 x]/3, {-Pi/6 < x < Pi/6}]

Comment: MMA11.2 Linux gives `-x + 1/3 Tan[3x]`.